# (Python, Kivy) How do I define by button functions properly? I keep getting AttributeError: 'Dice' object has no attribute 'DisplayBox'

Tags: python, kivy

I am working on a random dice roller project, Im new to python (I started learning it on my own about 2 months ago) and thought that it would be a good beginner project to work on. But I keep having trouble binding my functions to my buttons. I keep getting an AttributeError: 'Dice' object has no attribute 'displaybox'. Which I dont really understand because my Dice class clearly has a displaybox object inside of it. Thanks for any help!

Here is my Python code:

```
from random import randint

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Dice(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Dice, self).__init__(**kwargs)

# Define Buttons and labels
        d4btn = Button(text='D4',
                       bold = True,
                       on_press = self.rolld4)
        d6btn = Button(text='D6',
                       bold = True)
        d8btn = Button(text='D8',
                       bold = True)
        d10btn = Button(text='D10',
                        bold = True)
        d12btn = Button(text='D12',
                        bold = True)
        d20btn = Button(text='D20',
                    bold = True)
        displaybox = (Label(text=('You have not rolled, \n please select a number to roll.')))
        infobox = (Label(text='Random Dice Project \nJoshua \n10/17/2017'))
# Create Buttons and Labels
        self.add_widget(d4btn)
        self.add_widget(d6btn)
        self.add_widget(d8btn)
        self.add_widget(d10btn)
        self.add_widget(d12btn)
        self.add_widget(d20btn)
        self.add_widget(displaybox)
        self.add_widget(infobox)
# Button Behavior
    def rolld4(self, obj):
        self.displaybox.text = print(str(randint(1,4)))


class DiceRollerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Dice()        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DiceRollerApp().run()
```

And here is my Kivy code:

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Dice>:

    cols: 2
    rows: 4
```

Edit: I got a working version completed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to define all your widgets in your kv file, and use ObjectProperty to hook up to your display box. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from random import randint

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Dice(GridLayout):
    displaybox = ObjectProperty(None)

    # Button Behavior
    def rolld4(self):
        self.displaybox.text = str(randint(1, 4))


class DiceRollerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Dice()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DiceRollerApp().run()
```

### diceroller.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyButton@Button>:
    bold: True

<Dice>:
    displaybox: displaybox
    cols: 2
    rows: 4
    MyButton:
        text: "D4"
        on_press: root.rolld4()
    MyButton:
        text: "D6"
    MyButton:
        text: "D8"
    MyButton:
        text: "D10"
    MyButton:
        text: "D12"
    MyButton:
        text: "D20"
    Label:
        id: displaybox
        text: 'You have not rolled, \nplease select a number to roll.'
    Label:
        id: infobox
        text: 'Random Dice Project \nJoshua \n10/17/2017'
```

### Output

[image: Dice Rolled]

Answer (score 0):

in the init() of your dice you need to instanciate the displaybox as an attribute of the dice then you can manipulate it in the button behaviour, so your code is correct just add the self parameter and everything would work fine

here is the code:

-kv:

```
<Dice>:
   cols: 2
   rows: 4
```

-py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from random import randint
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class Dice(GridLayout):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(Dice, self).__init__(**kwargs)

# Define Buttons and labels
      d4btn = Button(text='D4',
                   bold = True,
                   on_press = self.rolld4)
      d6btn = Button(text='D6',
                   bold = True)
      d8btn = Button(text='D8',
                   bold = True)
      d10btn = Button(text='D10',
                    bold = True)
      d12btn = Button(text='D12',
                    bold = True)
      d20btn = Button(text='D20',
                bold = True)
      #Here you instantiate it ass an attribute of the dice
      self.displaybox = (Label(text=('You have not rolled, \n please select a number to roll.')))
      infobox = (Label(text='Random Dice Project \nJoshua \n10/17/2017'))

# Create Buttons and Labels
      self.add_widget(d4btn)
      self.add_widget(d6btn)
      self.add_widget(d8btn)
      self.add_widget(d10btn)
      self.add_widget(d12btn)
      self.add_widget(d20btn)
      #Then you add it to the layout
      self.add_widget(self.displaybox)
      self.add_widget(infobox)

# Button Behavior
  def rolld4(self, obj):
     self.displaybox.text = str(randint(1,4))
     print(str(randint(1, 4)))


class DiceRollerApp(App):

   def build(self):
      return Dice()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   DiceRollerApp().run()
```

proof:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

I hope I helped !